# How to replace a substring between two indexes ignoring HTML tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, replace, substring

I want to replace a substring in a text between two indexes. But I want to ignore any HTML tag when counting the index.

For example

If the text is **the best kitchen knife** I want to replace the substring from index 4 to 8 with 'nice' so the output should be **the nice kitchen knife**

But if the text is in HTML tag like
`<li>the best kitchen knife</li>`
or
`<li>the <span>best</span> kitchen knife</li>` and given indexes are 4 and 8, it should count from 'the' not from `<li>`. So the expected output should be `<li>the <span>nice</span> kitchen knife</li>`

I used the following code but it doesn't work as I'm expecting.

```
function replaceBetween(origin, startIndex, endIndex, insertion) {
    return (
        origin.substring(0, startIndex) + insertion + origin.substring(endIndex)
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
replaceBetween("<li>the <span>best</span> kitchen knife</li>", 4, 8, "nice");
```

Output:

```
<li>nice<span>best</span> kitchen knife</li>
```

Expected Output:

```
<li>The <span>nice</span> kitchen knife</li>
```

Comment: The code shown makes no attempt at all to handle the HTML tags. Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Note: Your best bet is to use an HTML parser to parse the string into some kind of DOM structure (on browsers you can do this with `DOMParser`; on Node.js, there are several `npm` parsers available). Then make you change based on the contents of the text nodes in the result, then serialize it back to a string. Handling HTML **properly** is hugely complex, even for what seems like a simple thing to do (as in this case).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to retrieve the `.innerText` of your `li element`. The returned value will not contain any html tags so you can manipulate the text as required. If the removed tags are needed, you'll have to put them back (by modifying the text string to include tags) and set the `li element`' .innerHTML` to your text string (where the browser will interpret the text as html markup).

The result of the `.innerText` retrieval is shown in the log of the following snippet:

```js
let txt = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].innerText;
console.log(txt);
```

```html
<ul>
<li>the <span style="color:red">best</span> kitchen knife</li>
</ul>
```